# How to use values from 2 columns in my dataframe to assign a new column using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

If my dictionary is

```
rate={
    (xyz,A): 10, 
    (abc,A): 1,
    (def,B): 100}
```

Dataset looks like

```
      Member    Group      Rate

 0     xyz       A         np.Nan
 1     uvw       B         np.Nan
 2     abc       A         np.Nan
 3     def       B         np.Nan
 4     ghi       B         np.Nan
```

How I want the final dataset to be like

```
      Member    Group      Rate

 0     xyz       A         10
 1     uvw       B         0
 2     abc       A         1
 3     def       B         100
 4     ghi       B         0
```

I am looking for a solution that uses the lambda function and apply.

PS: If the key in my dictionary was only dependent on one column then it is easy to solve this

```
df["Rate"] = df["Member"].apply(lambda x: rate.get(x))
```

but what should be done if the dictionary is dependent on 2 columns

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just modify the code to this -

1. Use `apply` function over the complete `df` over `axis=1` to get 1 row at a time.
2. For that `row` series, use lambda function to get tuple of `row.Member` and `row.Group` to fetch value from `rate` dictionary
3. If no key pair is found, return default value as 0

```
df.Rate = df.apply(lambda row: rate.get((row.Member,row.Group), 0), axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
  Member Group  Rate
0    xyz     A    10
1    uvw     B     0
2    abc     A     1
3    def     B   100
4    ghi     B     0
```